# d3 - How to change the force-directed graph's layout , to make it look like a tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've implemented this:
[force-directed-graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBFky.png)

However,I would like to change the force-directed graph's layout,to make nodes spread out from the center(or left to right),like this[force_directed-tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html):

And input data has ring,so I can't use d3.layout.tree().

Any assistance that you can provide is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't enforce any particular shape with the force layout.

Comment: I've implemented what I want using this:

Comment: I've implemented what I want, add the following code in tick function:

                        var kx = 1.4 * e.alpha, ky = .4 * e.alpha;
                        graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
                                d.target.x += (d.source.x + 80 - d.target.x) * kx;
                                d.target.y += (d.source.y - d.target.y) * ky;
                        });
and then the graph will look like a tree.